# cannot get confluence to run on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, confluence

After I attempted to install the confluence 5.8.6,

I followed mainly the steps in https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Installing+Confluence+on+Linux+from+Archive+File#InstallingConfluenceonLinuxfromArchiveFile-2.InstallJava and https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Start+Confluence+Automatically+on+Linux

I used `confluence` as user and run `. confluence-start.sh` inside `/usr/local/confluence/current/bin/`

Almost immediately, I get the following message and my user account got switched out of `confluence` and back into `ubuntu`

```
confluence@ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/usr/local/confluence/current/bin$ . start-confluence.sh

To run Confluence in the foreground, start the server with start-confluence.sh -fg
executing as current user
If you encounter issues starting up Confluence, please see the Installation guide at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Installation+Guide

Server startup logs are located in /usr/local/confluence/current/logs/catalina.out
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/confluence/current
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/confluence/current
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/confluence/current/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/confluence/current/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/confluence/current/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /usr/local/confluence/current/work/catalina.pid
Tomcat started.
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo su confluence
confluence@xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/home/ubuntu$ cd /usr/local/confluence
confluence@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/usr/local/confluence$ ls -la
```

I then tried ip address:8090. I get nothing.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

I have switched to java 8. Same issue

```
confluence@ip-172-31-22-135:/usr/local/confluence/current/bin$ . start-confluence.sh

To run Confluence in the foreground, start the server with start-confluence.sh -fg
executing as current user
If you encounter issues starting up Confluence, please see the Installation guide at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Installation+Guide

Server startup logs are located in /usr/local/confluence/current/logs/catalina.out
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/confluence/current
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/confluence/current
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/confluence/current/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/confluence/current/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/confluence/current/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /usr/local/confluence/current/work/catalina.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Tomcat started.
```

Answer (score 2):

Confluence 5.8 requires Java 8 and you are using Java 7

Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

switch to Java 8 and it should work fine!

Regards,
Gorka

Comment: I'd need the log to find out, could you upload it to pastebin or similar?

Comment: Where can I get the log? I have checked inside /usr/local/confluence/data. No log there.

Comment: There's a new add-on (haven't tried it though) that allows you to directly download the log https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.artemissoftware.confluence.plugins.tools.log-downloader.
Or in your confluence home folder, in the log folder, a file entitled "atlassian-confluence.log"

Comment: Have you configured EC2 firewall to open port 8090

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the port on your EC2 Instance?

Go to your Security Groups, click on Actions -> Inbound Rules and add the 8090 port.